# Filtering on RealmOptional removes values of nil, while CoreData predicate does not

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm

I've ported code from CoreData to Realm and everything is working great aside from 1 final issue.

Filtering when using a RealmOptional is removing all objects that have a value equal to nil.

For instance, `.filter("price <= 10.0")` is removing from the results set, all objects whose price is nil. This behaviour did not happen in CoreData when using NSFetchedResultsController and NSPredicates, so I'm wondering if this is expected behaviour for Realm?

The Object is as follow a `RealmOptional<Double>` in the example below:

```
class Product : Object, Mapper
{
    var price = RealmOptional<Double>() {
        // Using ObjectMapper library to map JSON to Realm hence willSet
        willSet {
            self.price = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect results to return all `Products` that have price < 10.0 including those with nil values.

Is this expected behaviour or simply a bug?

Comment: Hi! Marius here, from Realm. Could you elaborate on the comment in your sample code? This is looking like quite a hack and I see the danger that this could cause unexpected behavior, but I'd like to understand what brought you to that idea in the first place.

Comment: Hi Marius. I was porting code from Core Data that mapped a JSON response to the Entity Model. I found the ObjectMapper library, but had difficulties with the optional values as I couldn't map items to `let` variables. Also similar issues for `Lists`. I believe the code I followed is here https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That objects with null values are not included if you filter by a numeric comparison operator is the expected behavior. You can add `OR price = nil` if you'd like to include the objects where the `price` is `nil`. Like the following:

```
let free_or_cheap_products = realm.objects(Product)
    .filter("product <= 10 || product = nil")
```